# Using struct in place of function for FnOnce

Tags: rust

This program compiles and runs successfully.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError(i32);

fn main() {
    let m: Result<(), MyError> = Err(3).map_err(MyError);
    println!("{:?}", m); // output: Err(MyError(3))
}
```

The signature of `map_err` is

```
pub fn map_err<F, O: FnOnce(E) -> F>(self, op: O) -> Result<T, F>
```

which expects a `FnOnce`, for which I believe the type should be a function/closure. What is the reason the struct can be used successfully here?

Comment: This is [documented in the Rust reference as "tuple struct expression"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html#tuple-struct-expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you define a tuple struct, it defines the corresponding type as well as a constructor, which is a function, because why not. [You can actually check this using the compiler](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e19b405bb2aea452706ab52068d7d51e), the tuple struct constructor isn't even any sort of weird function-like item, it's a function pointer like any function you'd define using `fn` (or a non-closure anonymous function).

Both have the same name but live in different namespaces, one being the "types namespace" and the other the "function namespace".

A clearer version of this is *enum tuple constructors* as there is no confusion between the type and its constructor: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d76337f3301927cfca67200b64dfa89c but it's rather the same principle.